# Google Place API response localization issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have used Google Autocomplete.My web site is accessed by the different different countries all over the world. I have faced localization issue with almost all the countries.

**My Current Code**

**Script with restrict localization parameter**

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize&language=en"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Js**

```
function initialize() {

    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('other-address')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        console.log(place);
    });
}
```

I have test this autocomplete with below address

**Dantes Plads 7, 1556 Copenhagen, Denmark**

I will get below information on the console

```
route       : Dantes Plads
sublocality : København V
locality    : København
country     : Denmark
```

I need all the details with the restricted language means in English

Please help me on this concern.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be unreliable. Looking for a city or a country seems to work and return the English name (when available). Looking for a more specific address seems to always return the various address components in the local language.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I am okay with the city and country in English but almost all the times city is return in local language and i don't think google have not English data for the cities and countries. So if you have any solution for get cities in English languages than please help.

Comment: Well... *København* is translated in English by *Copenhagen*. *København V* for example is not translated. If this is an issue for you on these specific city names, you might want to open a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814

Comment: I have face this issue in almost all the city not for this specific city.

Comment: Well, as I said before, it seems inconsistent. If I type in "*torvegade*", the first suggestion is *Torvegade Copenhagen, Denmark*. But with your example, if I enter "*Dantes Plads*", the first suggestion is *Dantes Plads København V, Denmark*. Street names are never translated. So here, only "København V" is not translated. Other examples where it fails for you?

Comment: When i enter this address "Museumsplatz 1 1070 Vienna, Austria" it's return city 'Wine' rather than 'Vienna'.